# Protobuf/guava dependency issue

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers, guava

Im working on a project that uses protobuf. It is a java 8 project, so I want to take advantage of guavas various collectors such as `toImmutableList`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.11.1'
}
```

I'm running into an issue where protobuf is depending on guava version 28.1 for android which lacks the toImmutableX collectors. Because 28.1 is higher than 21.0 the android version is being used during compilation instead.

Is the best route just to exclude the gradle dependency coming from protobuf?

Answer (score 0):

If you update your own Guava dependency to 28.1-jre (or you might as well go the whole way to 28.2-jre, the newest version), that should give you both the collectors and any recently added features that protobuf needs.

Comment: The guava 21.0 dependency is provided at runtime already, so I wanted to avoid shading in a third(?) version of guava.

Comment: Ah, I see. My concern would be that protobuf might use a feature that was added after 21.0. (I don't know if it does or not, but given that 21.0 is 3 years old, I wouldn't be surprised.) If 21.0 is the version present at runtime, then your options are probably to [shade](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild#what-if-i-want-to-use-beta-apis-from-a-library-that-people-use-as-a-dependency) the Guava and protobuf that you're bringing or to downgrade protobuf (and perhaps other libraries you're using) to a version from that requires only Guava 21.0.

Comment: For now I've gone the exclusion route and excluded the guava coming from protobuf from being used as a transitive dependency. I'm shading in protobuf anyway so it should be fine.